# Can I find min,max or avg in a map reduce program without setting mapred.reduce.tasks=1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to understand how can we find min,max,Avg of a very large file using mapreduce. Setting number of reduce tasks to 1 , is an obvious solution but it is not optimal for a very large file. I was also looking into writing a chaining MR job but eventually , you end up using one reducer in the final job. Can some one shed some light, on any other way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: If you think having one reducer is not optimal, then you can try using the combiner before using one reducer. I believe you wont be required to make a big code/logic change in case of min & max.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any issue with using 1 reducer here, however big your input data set is. For this, you should use combiner functionality which shall return their local Max, local Min, local TotalSum and Count and pass on to single reducer. This way, the amount of data that goes till reducer is very less (directly proportional to number of mappers). Once this small data reaches the single reducer, you can find global Max and Min and for average divide the total sum by total count.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write the logic to figure out min,max or Avg in the reducer class. Moreover I believe finding out min,max,avg of a very large file will anyway generate a single output file.

Comment: Well.. Writing the logic inside the reducer is inevitable, that has to be done any how. what i am worried is using only one reducer, but it makes sense as the final output should be a single file. Thanks for your inputs.